# How to implement change detection on a postgres table in order to NOTIFY a nestjs backend

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, database-trigger

I want to display in a frontend (angular) app all todos belonging to a project and when they were closed on a chart. I'm using postgres as DB with a table `Todo`, which has a foreign key (fk_project_id) on the table `Project`.

With the help of this [medium article](https://medium.com/@simon.white/postgres-publish-subscribe-with-nodejs-996a7e45f88), I was able to setup a postgres notification trigger, which my nestjs backend listens to (see script below). After each `INSERT` or `UPDATE` my backend will check which project's t todo has changed and notify the frontent in a socket.io chanel for that specific project.

My Problem lies now for the action, that a user can remove a todo from a project. The current trigger will emit the removed todo without a `fk_project_id` and I'm unable to push the update to the project channel from which the todo was removed.

The only solution I can think is to add a second trigger for todos with `BEFORE UPDATE`, which is I think to expensive for the sole purpose of getting the previous `fk_project_id`.

Are there any other approaches I can use?

```js
import { Pool } from 'pg';

interface NotificationTriggerConfig {
    trigger: string;
    channel: string;
    table: string;
    connectionString: string;
}

const getNotificationTrigger = (config: NotificationTriggerConfig) => `
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ${config.trigger}() 
    RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
        PERFORM pg_notify('${config.channel}', row_to_json(NEW)::text);
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ${config.trigger} on "public"."${config.table}";

CREATE TRIGGER ${config.trigger}
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE  
    ON "${config.table}"
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE ${config.trigger}();
`;

export function createNotificationTrigger<T = any>(
    cb: (payload: T) => any,
    config: NotificationTriggerConfig
) {
    const { connectionString, channel } = config;
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const pool = new Pool({ connectionString, max: 10 });
        await pool.query(getNotificationTrigger(config));
        pool.connect((err, client) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return reject(err);
            }
            client.on('notification', (msg) => {
                if (msg.channel === channel) {
                    cb(JSON.parse(msg.payload));
                }
            });
            client.query(`LISTEN ${channel}`);
        });
        resolve(pool.end);
    });
}
```